# GRUB won't boot Windows Boot Manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Like it says in the title, I've dual booted Ubuntu and Windows Boot Manager. It worked and then it stopped working and just goes back to GRUB. My setup boots GRUB and then I pick the system. The only way to go back to Windows is actually just go into the UEFI and manually pick Windows Boot Manager.

Here's the script I found for launching Windows Boot Manager. Please help.

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  C617-20C7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C617-20C7
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. Or Windows that is not hibernated. Windows fast start up sets hibernations flag & Windows monthly updates often turn fast start up back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Umm... I can still mount the partition.

Comment: Is it read only when you mount it? Or does Windows need chkdsk which may partially work.

Comment: No, it isn't read-only. Everything I see there works, I can still boot into Windows and when I do it says "Loading..." and goes to the lock screen. I just want it to be easier as going to the UEFI and goes to easy mode then clicking Windows Boot Manager is kinda hard. I made GRUB the first thing to boot so I can pick every time I start my system.

Comment: Here's a screenshot, https://imgur.com/a/aaqryxA

Comment: It shows hiberfile. Do not know if that exists with fast start up both on and off or not. Many think they are doing a full shutdown, but default is with fast start up on. And even if you turned it off, if Windows did an update (which you may not even have seen), it probably turned it back on.

Comment: Never mind. Already disabled, still does not work. :(